# Javascript - HTML5 audio does not play on Android device

Tags: javascript, android, html, audio

I have a script which after a countdown should play a .ogg file. Given the size of the files, the one which should play after the countdown ends is around 16kb. Now the script appears to be fine and works well on the Desktop browser, but it will not play the 16kb ogg file on my Android device. I am unable to figure out what could be the issue. There is another ogg file which plays onClick and it plays on Android browser without any issues, so I don't think the file format is the case. Please check the code.

```js
var clickTimer;

$("#startClock").click( function(){
  var pose = document.getElementById("pose");
     if (clickTimer) {
        clearInterval(clickTimer);
     }
     var counter = document.getElementById('minutes').value;
     clickTimer = setInterval(function() {
     counter--;
      if (counter >= 0) {
         span = document.getElementById("count");
         span.innerHTML = counter;
      }
      if (counter === 0) {
        span = document.getElementById("count");
        pose.play();
               }
     },  1000);


});
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js?ver=4.1'></script>

<audio id="pose" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38489556/changepose.ogg" ></audio>

<div id="count">0</div>

<div id="min">Mins</div>
  <select id="minutes">
  <option value="6" selected="selected">1</option>
  </select>
 <button id=startClock >Start</button>
```

Comment: playing media needs to be the result of a user action, like a click()

Comment: Is that specific to the Android device? Because it plays fine on Desktop and the main intent is to let the user know the timer is up which needs to happen automatically.

Comment: yes, it's a newer policy on mobile, probably to save cpu / battery life. once a user plays an audio tag, using `controls` for example, you can then play() the tag again w/o intervention.

Comment: Is there any workaround to this because I want it to automatically play a sound once the countdown reaches to zero?

Comment: add controls to tag, hide with opacity 0, mute the tag, make the same click that starts the timer play() the muted tag, unmute the tag, set .currentTime=0, play() the tag when timer ends.

Comment: I can try that.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution to this. Below is the code with the changes, if someone face the similar issue.

```js
var clickTimer;

$("#startClock").click( function(){
  var pose = 
           document.getElementById("pose").play(); 
           document.getElementById("pose").pause(); 
     if (clickTimer) {
        clearInterval(clickTimer);
     }
     var counter = document.getElementById('minutes').value;
     clickTimer = setInterval(function() {
     counter--;
      if (counter >= 0) {
         span = document.getElementById("count");
         span.innerHTML = counter;
      }
      if (counter === 0) {
        span = document.getElementById("count");
        document.getElementById("pose").play(); 
               }
     },  1000);


});
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js?ver=4.1'></script>

<audio id="pose" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/38489556/changepose.ogg" ></audio>

<div id="count">0</div>

<div id="min">Mins</div>
  <select id="minutes">
  <option value="6" selected="selected">1</option>
  </select>
 <button id=startClock >Start</button>
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: It would be helpful to state what the fix was vs. just code.